# Why some applications such as Clash of Clans are for android 4.0 to higher?

Tags: android

Why some applications such as Clash of Clans are for android 4.0 to higher? While  we can with setting "android:minSdkVersion" equal to 8, we can use from a wide range of devices. Why some manufacturers do not put  "android:minSdkVersion" equal to 8? While this is useful and very easy!

Answer (score 3):

> Why some applications such as Clash of Clans are for android 4.0 to higher?

Either:

- They need some API or device feature that is only available on Android 4.0 and higher, such as `TextureView`, or
- They determined that older devices would not have the system requirements (CPU, GPU, RAM, etc.) that their app needs, or
- They did not want to spend the effort to test their app older devices, or
- Any other reason, as they have the freedom to choose to support whatever they want

> While we can with setting "android:minSdkVersion" equal to 8, we can use from a wide range of devices.

At the present time (June 2015), [~6% of Android devices using Google Play are running older than Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). That is a relatively small audience, and it is a declining audience. Supporting older devices can require substantial engineering and testing efforts, and developers will have to choose for themselves whether those efforts will be worth it for this slice of the Android ecosystem.

> While this is useful and very easy!

You are welcome to get a job with Supercell and demonstrate to them how easy it is.

Answer (score 0):

minSdkVersion is used to declare the min sdk version that your application really support.

You can not decrease the min version if you can't ensure that all api levels are actually supported.

If you select minSdkVersion as 8, your application will reach more devices. But you must change your app to support all  android versions >= 8. Otherwise, your application won't work properly.

Several features were added in different version of android.. So, some stuffs are not directly supported.. It demands time to port to older versions or maybe, it could not be done in older versions.

It's a design/project choice.